# where i can download server log for analyze with reponse time

Tags: apache, logging, access-log

Please give me server log, for example **apache access_log** for analyze **with reponse time**.
I am learning create profile testing, so i need log with url, time and response time.
I have found without response time https://gist.github.com/rm-hull/bd60aed44024e9986e3c
GET /index.php?option=com_phocagallery&view=category&id=1:almhuette-raith&Itemid=53 HTTP/1.1" 200 32653 ... ???